# Can not read data via linq from ef

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two related models and want to read via linq

```
using (var ctx = new TextsContext())
{
    var data = from e in ctx.Text
               where e.LanguageCode == lang
               select e;

    foreach (var d in data)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(d.Language, d.Fieldname);
    }
}
```

First model

```
public class Language
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Second model

```
public class Text
{
    public string Fieldname { get; set; }
    public string LanguageCode { get; set; } // Add this foriegn key property
    public string Description { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
}
```

I am using code first(Fluent API) to build relationship between the two tables. 
When I want to query with linq, I've got error message:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which
>   must be closed first.

Comment: Please post the *full* exception, including the call stack *and* the mapping code. You can get the full exception by calling `Exception.ToString()`. The code you posted wouldn't throw such an exception if you used only this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that if you do a the `Include()` and `ToList()` it will solve it. Probably because of the lazy loading of linq while it iterates it creates another reader in order to get the other entity (`Language`).

```
using (var ctx = new TextsContext())
{
    var data = (from e in ctx.Text.Include("Language")
               where e.LanguageCode == lang
               select e).ToList();

    foreach (var d in data)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(d.Language, d.Fieldname);
    }
}
```